# POSIX Shell Escape Quotes in Dynamic String

Tags: string, function, sed, sh, posix

Say I have a function that accepts a string and interpolates it inside quotes.

```bash
print_str() (
printf '"%s"\n' "$1" 
)
```

Since the function encloses the input in double quotes, I want to escape all double quotes, if any, in the argument. But, critically, double quotes that are already escaped must be preceded by a backslash. In short, the function must add one layer of escaping to all double quotes in the argument, be that the first layer or an additional layer.

Examples:

- `'abc"def'` -> `'abc\"def'`
- `'{ "json": "{ \"key\": \"value\" }" }'` -> `'{ \"json\": \"{ \\\"key\\\": \\\"value\\\" }\" }'`

The tricky part for me is determining whether a backslash preceding a double quote is actually escaping the double quote, because, for example, in `'\\"'` the backslash does not escape the double quote even though it immediately precedes the double quote.

I've thought about using `sed` and checking whether the number of backslashes before a double quote is odd or even, but that seems pretty convoluted. I managed to get the solution I wanted by piping the input through `jq -R .`, but I am wondering if there is another way to do it. In particular, I am looking for something that works in POSIX shell.

EDIT:

For further clarification, I am seeking *some* function that will add an additional layer of escaping to double quotes in a given string.

```bash
some_function() {
# IDK what the implementation would be
}
```

Then, `some_function` in conjunction with `print_str` would producing the following output.

```bash
string='{ "json": "{ \"key\": \"value\" }" }'
print_str "$(some_function "$string")"
# -> prints "{ \"json\": \"{ \\\"key\\\": \\\"value\\\" }\" }"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to count anything

```
sed 's/["\]/\\&/g; s/.*/"&"/'
```

Comment: It looks like this works. Very nice, thank you.